# Need help with this .get() script

Tags: jquery

I am fetching value using jQuery .get() like this

```
    $.get('clientarea.php', function(data) {
      var Val = $('#abc', data).val();
       if (this.val() == 'YES') {
         // do this
        }
        else {
        // do that
        }
    });
```

Using .get() I want to compare value of `#abc` [whether 'YES' or 'NO'] & then use conditional command to define further action.

But I am doing something wrong with above script. can anybody correct me.

**Thanks**

Comment: Wouldn't you want to compare Val, then, if that's defined to be the value of #abc?

Comment: @ james Curran: just an <input type="text"> value

Comment: the value of #abc is stored in Val,shouldn't u be checking that if its YES or NO

Comment: @manraj82 I think you are spot on there. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
$.get('clientarea.php', function(data) {
    var val = $('#abc', data).val();
    if (val == 'YES') {
        // do this
    }
    else {
        // do that
    }
});
```